# Grouped_select: How to show specific selection under a group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**1. Context**

In a reservation form, I only would like to show rooms that are available.

In my simple_form I use a dropdown menu, via grouped_select. Hereby a user sees a room_category and underneath the (available) rooms belonging to this room_category.

**2. Issue**

I am able to show all rooms under room_category. But I don't know how to show a specific selection of rooms under each room_category.

**3. Previous attempts**

- I tried specifying it under @room_categories, but this (obviously) didn't work, as it only deletes a room_category when no rooms are available for this category.
- I tried specifying the `group_method` to @rooms, but this gave an error message:

```
nil is not a symbol nor a string
```

**4. Code**

form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@hotel, @reservation] do |f|%>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-sm-3">
        <%= f.input :arrival,
        as: :string,
        label:false,
        placeholder: "From",
        wrapper_html: { class: "inline_field_wrapper" },
        input_html:{ id: "start_date"} %>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-sm-3">
        <%= f.input :departure,
        as: :string,
        label:false,
        placeholder: "From",
        wrapper_html: { class: "inline_field_wrapper" },
        input_html:{ id: "end_date"} %>
      </div>
<%= f.input :room_id, collection: @room_categories.order(:name), as: :grouped_select, group_method: :rooms,  label:false %>

        <%= f.button :submit, "Search", class: "create-reservation-btn"%>

    <% end %>

<script>
const checkIn = document.querySelector('#start_date');
const checkOut = document.querySelector('#end_date');
const checkInAndOut = [checkIn, checkOut];

checkInAndOut.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    checkAvailability();
  })
})

    function checkAvailability(){

      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= rooms_availability_hotel_path(@hotel) %>" ,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: `arrival=${start_date.value}&departure=${end_date.value}`,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    };
  </script>
```

hotels_controller

```
def rooms_availability
  hotel = Hotel.includes(:rooms).find(params[:id])
  arrival = Date.parse room_params[:arrival]
  departure = Date.parse room_params[:departure]
  time_span = arrival..departure
  @unavailable_rooms = Room.joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {hotel: hotel}).where("reservations.arrival <= ? AND ? >= reservations.departure", arrival, departure).distinct
  hotel_cats = hotel.room_categories
  hotel_rooms = Room.where(room_category: hotel_cats)
  @rooms = hotel_rooms - @unavailable_rooms
  authorize @rooms
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

models

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :room
end

class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room_category
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :room_category
end

class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :room_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :rooms, through: :room_categories
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
end

class RoomCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In docs:

`group_method - The name of a method which, when called on a member of collection, returns an array of child objects representing the <option> tags. It can also be any object that responds to call, such as a proc, that will be called for each member of the collection to retrieve the value.`

so maybe Proc is an option?

`<%= f.input :room_id, collection: @room_categories.order(:name), as: :grouped_select, group_method: Proc.new{ |room_category| room_category.scope_or_method_to_get_available_rooms(@arrival, @departure) },  label:false %>`

and if you want to do it dynamically try inject that line by executing `js.erb` view template in effect of AJAX

```
$("input[name*='room_id']").replaceWith("<%= j(f.input :room_id, collection: @room_categories.order(:name), as: :grouped_select, group_method: :rooms,  label:false)%>")
```

of course written exactly like that it wont work without `f` form builder object, but you will easily find way to replace form builder method with simply `grouped_collection_select`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm trying it out right now! I'm new to this, and I was wondering how you would get the ```@arrival``` & ```@departure``` from the form into the method?

Comment: Solved it by including ```group_by: proc { |room| room.room_category.name }```